# round decimals to a specific value with php

Tags: php

I am trying to make a float number e.g. 110.34 to "round" to 110.90
The thing is I am converting product prices caused by currency switcher and I want to make the values values look good.

I have somewhere the function

```
function($price)
```

which gives me the price of the product.

And I was trying to make it with the round() function e.g.

```
return round($price * 2, 0) / 2;
```

But this will round it to x.00 or x.50

Is there any other function that can round all values to x.90?

Comment: This question is incomplete. Which decimals would you want to round _up_ to `.9`, and which one _down_ to it?

Comment: thanks for reply, all actually. i want to have 119.90 for example in EUR and USD 129.90 like this. Or maybe i can round to 0 and add 0.90

Answer (score 0):

Now i made it like this?

```
return intval($price) + 0.90;
```

is this the right way, at least it looks good. :-D

Comment: If `$price` is always a float, then you can simply use a cast like `(int)$price`. `intval()` is a function and will have more impact on performance. It probably won't be much, but it's a good thing to understand the difference if you're just starting out.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Let me try. :-) i will post me result soon